# Problem While Doing Plyometric Pushups

Tags: push-ups, calisthenics

Whenever i do plyometrics pushups my hands never fall in the same place they go completely side ways. Is this harmful and does this happen to everyone when they do plyo pushups or will this improve overtime? Please tell me a fix for this.(variations I do: clapping and explosive pushups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first do only easier variations of ex. push ups untill you are 100% sure of end position of your hands. Only then try more difficult variants. 
It will improve over time. I also had this problem, but it got better. But it won't be in 2 days. You just need to train, but not every day give your body relax sometime.